# show a single element of an iterate array with for in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting the values ​​of this json https://swapi.co/api/people/1/ But I want to show only a "film" of the array "films", using the index of the array [] it shows me a single element, although, in the same way, javascript keeps iterating in the rest of the elements.

I doubt it is necessary to call the get () function to get each of the values.

I remain attentive to your comments, masters.

My code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  function get(URL, callback) {
    const typeRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
    typeRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        callback(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        callback(new Error(`Se produjo un error al realizar el request ${this.status}`));
      }
    }
    
    typeRequest.open("GET", URL);
    typeRequest.send(null);
  }
  
  function _handleError (err) {
    console.log(`Request failed ${err}`);
  }
  
  get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1', function (err, luke) {
    if (err) return _handleError;
    get(luke.homeworld, function (err, homeworld) {
      if (err) return _handleError;
      for(let p = 0; p < luke.films.length; p++) {
          get(luke.films[0], function (err, films) {
            if (err) return _handleError;
            console.log(films.title);
          })
      }
      luke.homeworld = homeworld;
      console.log(`Además, ${luke.name.substr(0, 4)} nació en el planeta ${luke.homeworld.name}`);
    })
    console.log(`Request succeded`);
    console.log(`Working by: ${luke.name}
    Height: ${luke.height}
    Peso: ${luke.mass}
    Color de cabello: ${luke.hair_color}
    Color de ojos: ${luke.eye_color}`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `for-loop` and just check the attribute `length`.

```
if (luke.films.length) {
    get(luke.films[0], function (err, films) {
        if (err) return _handleError;
        console.log(films.title);
    })
}
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
  function get(URL, callback) {
    const typeRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
    typeRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        callback(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        callback(new Error(`Se produjo un error al realizar el request ${this.status}`));
      }
    }
    
    typeRequest.open("GET", URL);
    typeRequest.send(null);
  }
  
  function _handleError (err) {
    console.log(`Request failed ${err}`);
  }
  
  get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1', function (err, luke) {
    if (err) return _handleError;
    get(luke.homeworld, function (err, homeworld) {
      if (err) return _handleError;
      if (luke.films.length) {
        get(luke.films[0], function (err, films) {
            if (err) return _handleError;
            console.log(films.title);
          })
      }
      luke.homeworld = homeworld;
      console.log(`Además, ${luke.name.substr(0, 4)} nació en el planeta ${luke.homeworld.name}`);
    })
    console.log(`Request succeded`);
    console.log(`Working by: ${luke.name}
    Height: ${luke.height}
    Peso: ${luke.mass}
    Color de cabello: ${luke.hair_color}
    Color de ojos: ${luke.eye_color}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ele, is what I needed